# This counter code is counting cells twice

Tags: python, csv, counter, defaultdict

I'm using this code to print the occurrences of non-numeric cells. However, it is doubling the count. Its printing 6 for 3.

Sample data:

```
pID,sID,dID,nID,ID
ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0002-UNK,2,123,ABCD
ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0004-UNK,3,1234,ABCD
ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0007-UNK,7,3455,ABCD
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import csv

header_counter = defaultdict(Counter)

with open('trial.csv') as input_file:
    r = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')
    headers = next(r)
    for row in r:
        row_val = sum([w.isdigit() for w in row])
        for header, val in zip(headers, row):
            if not any(map(str.isdigit, val)):
                header_counter[header].update({val: row_val})

for k, v in header_counter.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Current output `ID Counter({'ABCD': 6})`
Desired output `ID Counter({'ABCD': 3})`

Comment: What output do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: @kindall I want the count of only 'ABCD' to be printed and it should be 3. It does print only 'ABCD' but the count is 6.

Comment: Again, please post the output you are getting.

Comment: Just change `header_counter[header].update({val: row_val})` to `header_counter[header].update({val: 1})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So:

> ln 11`sum([w.isdigit() for w in row])`

Is returning the number of columns that are digits in each row, in your case two, cols `dID` ans `nID` are digits.

So `row_val` is integer 2 for all rows this triggers on.

> ln 14 `header_counter[header].update({val: row_val})`

Is adding `row_val` (2) every time.

Comment: This could be addressed by using `any()` instead of `sum()`.

Comment: @kindall Wow yeah, that was more elegant than what I was considering proposing (hard-coding true where the update call is).

Answer (score 0):

I expect your problem lies in how you're using update against the Counter, as update() adds to the count rather than replacing it as you might expect from a conventional dict. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

The output `ID Counter({'ABCD': 6})` is correct for the given input data and logic.

You are summing all numeric fields for each "ID" and reporting the count.

There are 6 total numeric fields for rows that have an ID of "ABCD", namely:

ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0002-UNK,**2**,**123**,ABCD
ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0004-UNK,**3**,**1234**,ABCD
ABCD-02-01,ABCD-02-01-0007-UNK,**7**,**3455**,ABCD

I'll update my answer if you explain what is your intended result is.